# mail sending using codignator liberary function delivered as spam

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendmail

I am using codeigniter framework. While send mails using codeigniter mail functions, mail is delivered as spam, i dont know why this happens, i am using code as:

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    if($fromname==''){$fromname='MySystem';}
    if($from==''){$from='noreply@gmail.com';}
    if($reply==''){$reply=$from;}
    $config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => host,
    'smtp_port' => port,
    'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
    'smtp_user' => user_nam,
    'smtp_pass' => pwd,
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
   );
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from($from, $fromname);
    $this->email->reply_to($reply, $fromname);
    foreach($result as $row){
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message1);

    $this->email->send();
    }
```

By using this code, a mail is sending to a group of users. This mails are received as spam mails. Is this because of some error in code or a server issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My Mails Is Always Going To Spam Folder Even Delivering Very Late In Codeigniter Php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986619/my-mails-is-always-going-to-spam-folder-even-delivering-very-late-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is likely your `from` address. When sending email, you are saying the sender is `noreply@gmail.com`. When your email is received, the service will look up Gmail's SPF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) DNS record to see if the server that sent the email (your server) is a server which Gmail say is a permitted sender, which of course it's not. Since that check fails, the email is very likely to end up in spam.

The way to fix that is to set your `from` address to a real domain, e.g. `noreply@yourdomain.com`. Then you need to set an SPF record so that your server is a trusted sender for that domain. There are heaps of tutorials out there to help with that, but you could simply use this as a TXT record on yourdomain.com:

```
v=spf1 ip4:<your server IP> ~all
```

If you send email from yourdomain.com from other services (e.g. Google Apps) you'll want to add rules for that too.

Even with that, your emails aren't guaranteed to stay out of spam. If the content of the messages is simplistic and spam-like, or if you don't include an unsubscribe link, you could also end up in spam.

Comment: if $from is NULL then only this var is set as : 'noreply@gmail.com' if($from==''){$from='noreply@gmail.com';}

Comment: Same principle applies, though. Is the email you end up sending from an authorised sender designated by an SPF record on that domain?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it fine by changing $config and initialize($config)

```
$config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => $host,
        'smtp_port' => $port,
        'smtp_crypto' => $crypto,
        'smtp_user' => $user_nam,
        'smtp_pass' => $pwd,
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'utf-8',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE,
        'smtp_auth' => TRUE
       );
  
   $this->load->library('email', $config);
   $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
   $this->email->initialize($config);
```

**Email Preferences**

The following is a list of all the preferences that can be set when sending emails.

[image]

Few tips to avoid mail delivered as spam:

- **Whitelist** your email address
- Get **Permission** to send emails
- **Satisfy the Rules** governing email marketing
- Use a proper email marketing **Program**
- **Do not write** a spammy subject
- **Avoid red-flagged words** from the content
- Regularly **remove in-active addresses** associated with email accounts
- Use **Spam checkers**
- Use **proper & clear** sender address
- Try to add **Unsubscribe** link