# My Mails Is Always Going To Spam Folder Even Delivering Very Late In Codeigniter Php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm Trying To Send Mails From My Web Server Using SMTP PROTOCOL in codeigniter frame work.my mails was always delivering late and going to spam.i had follow many past conservations,still i didn't solve this problem.help me folks to solve this problem.here is my code:

```
$config = Array('protocol' => 'smtp',
                       'smtp_host' => 'http://smtp.tfas.net/',
                       'smtp_port' => 465,
                       'smtp_user' => 'info@tfas.net',
                       'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxx',
                       'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                       'mailpath' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
                       'charset'   => 'utf-8'
                        );
      $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      if (file_exists($attachment_path)) 
      {
        $this->email->attach("$attachment_path");
        $this->email->from('info@tfas.net','TFAS MEMBER PORTAL');
        $this->email->reply_to('info@tfas.net','Help Center');
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject('Greetings From TFAS Member Portal');
      }
      else
      {
        $this->email->from('info@tfas.net','TFAS MEMBER PORTAL');
        $this->email->reply_to('info@tfas.net','Help Center');
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject('Greetings From TFAS Member Portal');
      }
        if($this->email->send())
        {
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
```

// Even I had gone through this link `https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer`  which is a tutorial to send mails with phpmailer library in codeigniter but same problem araises..

Comment: Nothing about your code controls whether the email is going into client spam folders. The problem is in the content -- you are putting text in your email that is apparently being identified as spam. The thing is, your spam filter and my spam filter have nothing to do with one another. My email client (Gmail) might deliver an email to my inbox that your email client (let's say Outlook) considers junk. As far as "delivering late", I am not sure what you mean, but that is also not a factor related to your PHP code. That's why you haven't been able to solve the problem by looking at your script.

Comment: ... are you sending spam?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is an issue with codeigniter's mailer. Usually, emails are marked as spam by email service providers based on the content or an IP filter. In your case it's possible that your content appear spam-like due to not having relevant text and images. Google and most providers has a list of spam words that they look out for when evaluating the spam-ness of your emails. Check this out as it may be help you to find a useful lead: http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/30684/The-Ultimate-List-of-Email-SPAM-Trigger-Words.aspx